# THREE.ObjLoader generating duplicate meshes from .obj file

Tags: three.js, .obj

I am loading a .obj file that builds a human dummy, and inside the .obj file there are lines that show where the meshes split E.G. "g "body_part" followed by the vertices, and faces. When I load my object it works great, and I can console log the object and see the children which are all the different meshes that build the object. The problem is that when I am using raycaster to change the color of the mesh that is hovered it will only work on specific parts. After further investigation I found that when the object is being loaded it is generating duplicates of the same mesh. Does anyone have an explaination on why it is duplicating duplicate meshes or a solution to this?

A hack to get the raycasting to work when hovering over a mesh is to choose the last index of the array returned by intersection, but this is a hack and does not fix the duplication problem. I am still investigating.

```
// store reference to closest object as current intersection object
this.INTERSECTED = intersects[intersects.length - 1].object;
```

Also, if I log the intersects it returns the correct mesh being intersected, but it returns all of the duplicates with it as well. For example when I hover over a hand it returns an array of the same object except they have different uids:

```
(9) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0
:
{distance: 158.11485222188028, point: Vector3, object: Mesh, uv: Vector2, face: Face3, …}
1
:
{distance: 158.11485222188028, point: Vector3, object: Mesh, uv: Vector2, face: Face3, …}
2
:
{distance: 158.11485222188028, point: Vector3, object: Mesh, uv: Vector2, face: Face3, …}
3
:
{distance: 158.11485222188028, point: Vector3, object: Mesh, uv: Vector2, face: Face3, …}
4
:
{distance: 158.11485222188028, point: Vector3, object: Mesh, uv: Vector2, face: Face3, …}
5
:
{distance: 158.11485222188028, point: Vector3, object: Mesh, uv: Vector2, face: Face3, …}
6
:
{distance: 158.11485222188028, point: Vector3, object: Mesh, uv: Vector2, face: Face3, …}
7
:
{distance: 158.11485222188028, point: Vector3, object: Mesh, uv: Vector2, face: Face3, …}
8
:
{distance: 158.11485222188028, point: Vector3, object: Mesh, uv: Vector2, face: Face3, …}
length
:
9
__proto__
:
Array(0)
```

Loading object:

```
  loadModel = (objModel) => {
    //ADD Obj instantiate a loader
    this.THREE = THREE;
    const objLoader = new this.THREE.OBJLoader();
    this.obj;

    // load(URL, callback, loading, on error)
    objLoader.load(objModel,
      //called when resource is loaded
      (object) => {
        object.traverse( function ( child ) {

          if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh ) {
            if(child.name == "dummy_hips3 dummy_belly dummy_torso dummy_rshoulder dummy_rarm dummy_relbow dummy_rfarm dummy_rwrist dummy_rhand") {
              console.log(child) <-- This will log 8x, and it should only happen once
            }
              child.material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0x444444, wireframe: true});
          }
        });

      object.position.y = -100;
      this.obj = object;
      console.log(object)
      this.scene.add(object);
      },
      //called when loading is in progresses
      (xhr) => {
        this.setState({
          percentageLoaded: (xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100).toFixed(2) + '%'
        });
      },
      //called when loading has errors
      (error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
```

Raycasting function

```
  findObjIntersection = (obj) => {
    // find intersections
    // create a Ray with origin at the mouse position
    //   and direction into the scene (camera direction)
    var vector = new THREE.Vector3(this.state.mouse.x, this.state.mouse.y, 1);
    vector.unproject(this.camera);
    var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster(this.camera.position, vector.sub(this.camera.position).normalize());

    // create an array containing all objects in the scene with which the ray intersects
    // You can also pass this.scene.children for other objects
    var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(obj);

    // INTERSECTED = the object in the scene currently closest to the camera 
    // and intersected by the Ray projected from the mouse position     

    // if there is one (or more) intersections
    if (intersects.length > 0) {
      // if the closest object intersected is not the currently stored intersection object
    if (intersects[0].object != this.INTERSECTED) {
      // restore previous intersection object (if it exists) to its original color
      if (this.INTERSECTED) this.INTERSECTED.material.color.setHex(this.INTERSECTED.currentHex);
        // store reference to closest object as current intersection object
        console.log(intersects)
        this.INTERSECTED = intersects[0].object;
        // store color of closest object (for later restoration)
        this.INTERSECTED.currentHex = this.INTERSECTED.material.color.getHex();
        // set a new color for closest object
        this.INTERSECTED.material.color.setHex(0xff0000);

        this.setState({
          INTERSECTED: this.INTERSECTED.name
        });
    }
    } else { // there are no intersections
    // restore previous intersection object (if it exists) to its original color
    if (this.INTERSECTED) this.INTERSECTED.material.color.setHex(this.INTERSECTED.currentHex);
      // remove previous intersection object reference
      // by setting current intersection object to "nothing"
      this.INTERSECTED = null;

      this.setState({
        INTERSECTED: 'False'
      });
    }
  }
```

I am showing what mesh is intersected, and it turns red as it is supposed to but only when I am in certain spot hovering the arm and I need it to happen when any of the arm is being hovered.
[image]

[image]

Here is the second image where the arm is being hovered, and it is detecting the intersection and displaying that it is indeed the same arm, but since I am not hovering over a specific spot it is returning a duplicate mesh that has a different id and this is where the problem is.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that the duplicates are in your obj file. The raycaster returns every object hit by the ray, so if you're getting 8 hits, there are 8 copies of the geometries there.

Are you exporting from Blender? There may be other copies in another layer, or hidden?

edit: I downloaded your model and viewed it in blender. The geometry is duplicated Up to 6 times for some segments of the object. This is not an uncommon problem because as a modeller, you may not notice the duplicates because they are identical copies within the same mesh.

[image: Here's a screenshot of the parts ive separated so far...]

Mesh obj size went from like 2.5 megs, down to ~350 k :)

In blender, you can go into edit mode on an object, select a single vertex, then hit Ctrl-L (select linked vertices) and then move that chunk of geometry, and it reveals a duplicate left behind.

The good news is that once these dupes are stripped out, your model file is going to be much much smaller. :)

eidt:1.5 I found an easier way to clean this model up.. selecting all the parts, then space bar->split->Separate by loose parts.. that turns each duped mesh into a separate object that was easy to select and get rid of.

edit2: Here's the cleaned up OBJ file with dupes removed.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Oi-hA9biuZmYuQ6ehiISOUZqCJDxd_fi

Comment: That was my original thought, and I believe the model was exported from maya based on where I got it from : https://www.turbosquid.com/FullPreview/Index.cfm/ID/662719.

I ran a basic powershell script to check for duplicates of a line in the file and it turned up false, so I do not think that is the issue.

Would you like me to post the .obj file?

Comment: yes please, looking for the line duplicate may not be enough

Comment: I found your problem.

Comment: Thank you so much. I just saw this and should of responded earlier saying the .obj file had duplicates. Thank you again.